# (Ghost of) Excel Camera Tool - Make it go away

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

We use spreadsheets as forms. I was experimenting with the camera tool for a form. Later I abandoned the idea. I have no more images in the sheet. Now when I enter anything in cells, or use F2 to edit a cell, an image appears!

It's not even the image of the range I used the camera tool for in the first place. It has top, left coordinates same or near the edited cell but is several rows and columns -worth larger. If I select that region, the image disappears immediately. But my users would not be amused, as they must make hundreds of entries in these forms, which we save-as records of our work. We have thousands of these form files. We archive them more-or-less forever.

Now I may have to make my new improved form from scratch. I'd like to avoid that.

See comments below. It may not even be a camera-tool issue, though I still suspect it. If you do:

```
Dim ss As Shapes, s As Shape
Set ss = ActiveSheet.Shapes
For Each s In ss
    Debug.Print s.Name
Next s
```

You will get "Picture"... listed for camera images. With my problem on
the screen, no such Picture is listed. The problem may be due to selection_
change event code I have (seem to happen only on cells I use it on). Or it may be due to sparklines. I've used the event code for years. The camera-tool and sparklines are new to these forms, so I suspect them.

Last edit. Perhaps question should be deleted. I now think the problem is caused by editing my win7-office10 document on a win10-office13 PC and then copying the resulting file back to win7-office10 PCs where they will live. I have confirmed the symptoms occur on every PC the file is used on. **Looks** like a camera-tool ghost, indeed probably has something to do with it, but more a MS bug than a SU topic.

[This shows the symptom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAMxt.png)

Comment: What's the selection_ change code? Are there other names of different shapes?

Comment: You never showed the SelectionChange code. Also, is it possible to get a screenshot of these strange images?

Comment: I don't have the rep to post images so SU converted it to a link. The amount of code I would have to paste is just too much, if I include the code that it calls. Besides, that same code has run for years without issue. This is one of those things we just need to cut our losses on; by forgetting it.

Comment: On occasion I've seen ghost images like that. I've usually attributed them to an overloaded system. I usually have several workbooks open, and never less than 57 browser tabs, and usually Word our PowerPoint too. They're fleeing, so I usually just shrug until they go away.

Answer (score 1):

Since the camera creates a live image in a drawing object, you can delete it just like an inserted picture.

- Click the image that appears
- Press delete

You will have to do this for each instance of camera created. Unless you write code to remove picture objects from the file. The problem there is if you have other images in the file you want to keep.

Comment: No can do. Cannot click or right-click on image. It immediately disappears if you try. But until then it stays. It has a different appearance - no border. If it randomly happened to align itself on the gridlines, you may not even notice it.

Comment: There is something else going on, or is wrong, preventing you from deleting them. Is the sheet/workbook/file protected in any way?

Comment: No. And they are not camera-tool images or shape objects. But they never happened before camera-tool was used. It's as if it happens at the OS or Application level screen-paint. It is random too. Eventually I'll get a screenshot.

Comment: You should update your question to include those details so people don't have to find them in the comments here. Maybe someone else might have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F11 to enter the VB Editor.

Press Ctrl+G to activate the Immediate Window.

Type this code into the Immediate Window, and press Enter:

`activesheet.pictures.delete`

Press Alt+F4 to close the VB Editor.

Voila, all camera objects (and other pictures are gone.

Comment: Jon, you are one of my heroes but I should modify the title of my question. I modified the body though - see text after the code snippet - no picture objects. Lately suspect problem is due to editing file on my Win10-Office13 box at home then at work on Win7-Office10. As such I think I should bug MS about their bug - not a topic for SU.

Comment: I don't think it's just due to editing on different machines. Must be something funny in your code. Do you have other camera pictures in the worksheet? More than half a dozen?

Comment: No other pictures. Four check-box controls that have been there for years with no issue. There are some merged cells - I saw some mention that camera objects and merged cells are a bad combination. The event code is not dealing with form, activeX, or picture objects, but it does cause sheet recalculation. But that code has been the same for years. I really think it's the intersection of camera-too and Excel-2013 on Win10.

Comment: Well, yeah, merged cells are the devil's spawn. Are the check boxes from the Form controls or ActiveX?